# Wordpress "FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined" appears when I install my plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, notice

When I install my woo-commerce plugin, wordpress shows this notice:

> FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined in /var/www/vhosts/*****.**/httpdocs/wp-config.php

When I deactivate the plugin the notice disappears.
Now the strange thing is that I have never made this define inside my plugin.

Can anyone help me understand why this notice appears and how it's connected  to my plugin if at all.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is "your woo-commerce plugin"? Are you sure that it does not define that constant a second time?

Comment: The plugin reads data from database and sends them to a REST API. It also catches events (eg customer register) and sends the data to another REST API.
It also has a page in the admin panel with a form that submits the data to another REST API.

Comment: And you are sure that the code of that plugin does not define that constant?

Comment: Yes, I made sure by searching thoroughly.

Answer (score 8):

The constant FORCE_SSL_LOGIN can be set to true to force all logins to happen over SSL. This (and all other such definitions) must be placed before

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

in the file, otherwise they will not take effect.

encountered the same problem and moving the code to above the line :

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

in wp-config.php solved the problem.

Comment: Are you sure about that? It should be irrelevant where you define a constant in your code.

Comment: This is already mention in document as well.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: No, it only mentions that the constant shall be defined before the first include of another file

Comment: This plugin for what?

Comment: What do you mean by that question?

Comment: I mean custom plugin will do what?

Comment: Still don't get it - how should I know what any random custom plugin does?

Comment: just go to wp-config file

Comment: What I find strange is that it appears when I install my plugin and disappears after I deactivate the plugin. If it was a problem with the define shouldn't it appear all the time and not only when I install my plugin?

Comment: please paste some code because we can't assume what written in

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post the whole code publicly but I can post section of it. So if you need any specific part let me know.

Comment: plugin about security related?

Comment: As per this answer, moving the FORCE_SSL_ADMIN above the  /* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */ comment in the code INDEED worked! Thanks.